# iOS convert date to string AM/PM

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

```
-(NSString *)calculateDateToString:(NSDate *)getDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:getDate];
    return  dateString;
}
```

This method work when time format 24H but if time came with AM/PM this method not work.

I set date format but still not work which part wrong any idea please help ?

EDIT :

```
-(NSString *)calculateDateToString:(NSDate *)getDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:getDate];
    NSDate *aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

    if(!aDate)
    {
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss a"];
        aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
    }

    NSString *dateStringReturn = [dateFormat stringFromDate:aDate];
    return  dateStringReturn;
}
```

Still return null which part wrong ??

EDIT 2 :

```
-(NSDate *)calculateStringToDate:(NSString *)getString
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:getString];

    if(!aDate)
    {
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss a"];
        aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:getString];
    }
    return aDate;
}
```

`getString` : 2015-02-16T14:45:00

Comment: Define "method not work". In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: @gokhancokkececi Change the second HH to hh and we are done.

Comment: If you want 12-hour time you need a 12-hour date format.  Study the spec!

Comment: As you can see 12h format exist in my code ? are you blind ?

Comment: A string like  `2015-02-16T14:45:00` with `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss a"];` won't work. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked for me :

```
-(NSDate *)calculateStringToDate:(NSString *)getString
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:getString];

    if( !aDate )
    {
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss a"];
        [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
        aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:getString];
    }

    return aDate;
}
```

When I have a string like 2015-02-16T14:45:00 and I want to format it to 12H format, I just need to define the good local. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) for more information.

Hope this can help ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output the date with the am/pm format use **a** , `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss a"];`

*EDIT:*

To do the opposite, convert from NSString to NSDate, you can use `dateFromString` that returns `nil` if the provided string doesn't conform to the format:

```
NSString StringDate=@"10:10:10 AM"; 
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:StringDate];
if(!aDate){
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
  aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:StringDate];
}
```

Comment: I want to use both time method

Comment: That method converts from NSDate to a NSString, if you need the opposite, check if the string has the required format with [dateFormatter dateFromString:StringDate], it will return *nil* if the format is wrong. I'll update the answer.

Comment: One more question timezone is important here ? Can i use UTC with 12H ?

Comment: Yes, you can use every timezone you want with the 12H dateformat.

Comment: You should use "yyyy" which means year not "YYYY" which means Year (in "Week of Year" based calendars).  See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)  
Also: [Date Field SymbolTable.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table)

Comment: Agree with @Zaph, +1.

Comment: What do you want to do? From NSDate->NSString or from NSString->NSDate? In your edit you convert from NSDate to NSString and then to NSDate again. That code was to convert a NSString to a NSDate. IF you want something like "10:30:10 AM" as output simply change `@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"` in your first sample to `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss a"` and for the NSDate you have as input you will have a string with AM/PM as output.

Comment: The NSDate is generic, doesn't have the concept of AM/PM. You DON'T need to perform any conversion if you just want to convert from NSDate to NSString, just use the correct date format with a **a** in it.

Comment: `2015-03-11 17:38:22.663 App[1283:255070] 2015-03-09T00:56:24
2015-03-11 17:38:22.665 App[1283:255070] CALCULATE DATE 2015-03-08 ÖS 10:56:24 +0000
2015-03-11 17:38:22.666 App[1283:255070] 2015-03-08T18:01:44
2015-03-11 17:38:22.667 App[1283:255070] CALCULATE DATE (null)
2015-03-11 17:38:22.667 App[1283:255070] 2015-03-05T20:57:00
2015-03-11 17:38:22.668 App[1283:255070] CALCULATE DATE (null)
2015-03-11 17:38:22.669 App[1283:255070] 2015-03-02T17:19:27
2015-03-11 17:38:22.670 App[1283:255070] CALCULATE DATE (null)`

First one is work but other ones still return null? interesting :)

Comment: Isn't the above 2nd code segment going to choke on "12:01:00 PM"?

Comment: `NSLog(@"DD%@",getString);
        NSString *ourString = @"06:30 AM";
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
        aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:ourString];` this code not work i can't understand ?

Comment: gokhan, when you print an NSDate it will be ALWAYS displayed with the default format **WITHOUT AM**, but the conversion worked, try parsing "06:30  PM", if you print aDate you will get  "18:30:00 +0000" not 6:30 or something else. If you want to print an NSDate with your own format, you have to use stringFromDate. If instead you see a date with minus/plus one hour, set the correct timezone to dateFormat.

Comment: I fixed the problem actually this code work but my phone language is Turkish i replace PM with ÖS now code work :)